# How to speed up this simple function in R

Tags: r, performance

I am trying to do Conway–Maxwell-Poisson regression using [COMPoissonReg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/COMPoissonReg/COMPoissonReg.pdf) in R

However, it is extremely slow for large dataset. Thus I tried to profile and check the source code.

The majority time (>95%) is spent on a function `COMPoissonReg:::computez`, which is equivalent to: [image]

```
test <- function (lambda, nu, max=100) 
{
    forans <- matrix(0, ncol = max + 1, nrow = length(lambda))
    for (j in 1:max) {
        temp <- matrix(0, ncol = j, nrow = length(lambda))
        for (i in 1:j) {
            temp[, i] <- lambda/(i^nu)
        }
        for (k in 1:length(lambda)) {
            forans[k, j + 1] <- prod(temp[k, ])
        }
    }
    forans[, 1] <- rep(1, length(lambda))
    ans <- rowSums(forans)
    return(ans)
}
```

`v` is nu here, and lambda is a vector, max is the upper-limit of `s` (here it is set to 100 as an approximate to infinity).

The question doesn't really need special background stats knowledge, but the [link](https://www.galitshmueli.com/system/files/JRSS-COM-Poisson.pdf) or [link2](https://doi.org/10.1214/09-AOAS306) is here just in case.

A simple script to test performance, this takes 8 secs, and if I lazily `cmpfun` compile it, it takes 4 secs. I believe it has the potential to be further improved. (without rewriting in C, and I am aiming for around ~ 0.05 sec so that I don't have to refactor the code in package which iteratively calls this function.)

```
lambda <- rnorm(10000, 1.5, 0.3)
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
sum(log(test(lambda, 1.2)))
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)
```

#### Update

I realized another issue: floating point arithmetic limitation. Doing power series is dangerous, it can overflow very soon, especially if we have to vectorize. E.g. `lambda ^ 100` is certainly `NAN` if `lambda` > 10000. Maybe I will use `reduce` if I program in other languages, but I fear in R reduce is slow.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at `Rcpp`. Rewriting the `computez` function should not be very hard.

Comment: meaningless title, you should edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slept on it, came up with another big improvement if you can use the gsl package. All you're doing is evaluating a polynomial:

```
require(gsl)
test5 <- function(lambda, nu, max=100){
gsl_poly(factorial(0:max)^-nu, lambda)
}

R>microbenchmark(test2(1:50,5.1), test4(1:50,5.1), test5(1:50,5.1))
Unit: microseconds
             expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 test2(1:50, 5.1) 4518.957 4838.5185 5318.5040 5617.6330 19978.039   100
 test4(1:50, 5.1) 2043.422 2268.3490 2472.0430 2727.1045 10328.376   100
 test5(1:50, 5.1)  311.144  407.2465  476.0755  540.6095  1138.766   100
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make it much faster than the function you are using by avoiding loops.  For example:

```
test2<-function(lambda,nu,max=100){
  len<-length(lambda)
  mm<-matrix(rep(lambda,each=max+1),max+1,len)
  mm<-mm^(0:max)
  mm<-mm/factorial(0:max)^nu
  colSums(mm)
}
```

This runs about 50 times faster with lambda of length 100:

```
> require(microbenchmark)
> lam<-rnorm(100)
> max(abs(test(lam,1.2)-test2(lam,1.2)))
[1] 4.510281e-16
> microbenchmark(test(lam,1.2),test2(lam,1.2),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
            expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  test(lam, 1.2) 77.124705 77.422619 78.241945 79.635746 81.260280    10
 test2(lam, 1.2)  1.335716  1.373116  1.401411  1.507765  1.562447    10
```

You can probably optimize it a little more, but this should get most of the gains, unless there is some kind of builtin function you can exploit rather than doing the sum explicitly.

On input of length 10000, it takes 0.148 seconds on my machine, versus 6.850 seconds for `test`:

```
> lam<-rnorm(10000)
> max(abs(test(lam,1.2)-test2(lam,1.2)))
[1] 3.552714e-15
> system.time(test2(lam,1.2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.132   0.016   0.148 
> system.time(test(lam,1.2))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.780   0.056   6.850
```

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if we can utilize `cumprod` somehow, without the burden of `apply`, as I need a further 10x improvement to make it handle my dataset well.

Comment: 10x is going to be tough in R.  I would take a look at `Rcpp`, it's pretty easy to use, and might get you the improvement you want.

Answer (score 3):

OK, here's an Rcpp answer.  As expected, it's a lot faster than either of the others.

```
require(Rcpp)
rcppfun<-"
Rcpp::NumericVector myfun(Rcpp::NumericVector lambda,
Rcpp::NumericVector weights)
{
  int num = lambda.size();
  int max = weights.size();
  std::vector<double> r(num);
  for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
    double total = 0;
    double prod = 1;
    for(int j=0; j<max; j++){
      total += prod/weights[j];
      prod *= lambda[i];
    }
    r[i]=total;
  }
  return Rcpp::wrap(r);
}
"
testRcpp<-cppFunction(rcppfun)
test5<-function(lambda,nu,max=100){
    wts<-factorial(0:max)^nu
    testRcpp(lambda,wts)    
}
```

This is about 40x faster than my original `test2` and about 12x faster than than @NealFultz's improved logarithmic implementation.

```
> lam<-abs(rnorm(10000))
> max(abs(test5(lam,1.2)-test2(lam,1.2)))
[1] 7.105427e-15
> microbenchmark(test2(lam,1.2),test3(lam,1.2),test4(lam,1.2),test5(lam,1.2))
Unit: milliseconds
            expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
 test2(lam, 1.2) 125.601616 126.790516 127.700099 135.182263 222.340179   100
 test3(lam, 1.2) 125.523424 126.666410 126.921035 131.316254 178.633839   100
 test4(lam, 1.2)  41.734015  42.640340  43.190553  50.932952  97.765219   100
 test5(lam, 1.2)   3.432029   3.501046   3.519007   3.532603   3.754232   100
```

On edit, here's one more Rcpp version that should at least partially address the overflow issue, by computing each term incrementally, rather than the numerator and denominator separately.

```
rcppfun2<-"
Rcpp::NumericVector myfun2(Rcpp::NumericVector lambda, Rcpp::NumericVector nu){
int num = lambda.size();
int max = nu.size();
std::vector<double> r(num);
for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
  double term = 1;
  double total = 1;
  for(int j=0; j< max; j++){
    term *= (lambda[i]/nu[j]);
    total += term;
  }
  r[i]=total;
}
 return Rcpp::wrap(r);
}
"

testRcpp2<-cppFunction(rcppfun2)
test6<-function(lambda,nu,max=100){
    testRcpp2(lambda,(1:max)^nu)
}

> lam<-abs(rnorm(10000))
> max(abs(test2(lam,1.2)-test6(lam,1.2)))
[1] 1.065814e-14
> microbenchmark(test5(lam,1.2),test6(lam,1.2))
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 test5(lam, 1.2) 3.416786 3.426013 3.435492 3.444196 3.604486   100
 test6(lam, 1.2) 3.554147 3.572285 3.580865 3.588030 3.840713   100
```

Comment: Looks pretty similiar to [Horners Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)

Comment: `testRcpp2` is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Following up @mrips, sometimes working on the log can be a bit faster because you can multiply instead of exponentiate:

```
test4 <- function(lambda,nu,max=100){
  mm<-matrix(log(lambda),max,length(lambda), byrow=TRUE) 
  mm<-mm * 1:max  -  nu*lfactorial(1:max)
  1 + colSums(exp(mm))
}
```

I've also factored out the special case where `s = 0`. Here's my timings:

```
R>microbenchmark(test2(1:50,5), test4(1:50,5))
Unit: microseconds
           expr     min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 test2(1:50, 5) 952.360 1432.6600 1436.4525 1440.1860 3467.981   100
 test4(1:50, 5) 695.189 1041.4785 1042.8315 1045.6525 2970.441   100
```

Comment: IMHO, you are adding assumptions (data needs to be positive) for no real significant improvement where length(lambda) == 1e4.

Comment: Lambda is positive for the poisson distribution.